# click through array via loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Hi I'm trying to build a slider where he fetches the click events from my array.
My plan was to go with a foreach loop through the array so that i can animate all the arrays. Now im struggling with the issue that: 1 He is going instantly through the hole array 2. he is giving me the error Animation to or from an underlying value is not yet supported.

EDIT: 
I want to animate my sliders automaticly adter buttonpush -> left : 0px;

PS: Im 80% Sure that this question is Stupid, sry im new to js/coding

```
function slider() {
  var forward = document.getElementById('forward');
  imageIDs.forEach(function (id) {
    forward.addEventListener('click', function () {
      console.log('in the Loop: ' + id);
      forward.animate({
        left: '0px'
      },1500);
    });
  });
}

slider();

HTML

<div id="sliderContainer">
  <div id="backward" class="backward"></div>
  <div id="forward" class="forward"></div>

  <div id="sliderWrapper" class="slider">
    <div id="slide1" class="slider">
      <img src="img/clouds-2517653_1920.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="slide2" class="slider">
      <img src="img/drop-of-water-2396748_1920.jpg"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `forward` is a native `HTMLElement`, in order to use `animate()` you need: `$(forward).animate(...)`

Comment: @haim770 no, its an experimental native feature, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Keyframe_Formats

Comment: @Jonasw, The way the OP calls it implies it's jQuery's `animate()`. The native one is expecting different arguments.

Comment: @haim770 just missig a [...] then its valid, and $() might not be self explaining for a newbie

Comment: @OP what do you want to see? Whats your html and css?

Comment: asynchronous calls don't "wait". you should use setTimeout to "schedule" your calls

Comment: @jonasw im trying to animate all the html ids for a slider, the ids are stored in an array

Comment: i still dont get it. and why do you do forward.animate() if forward is a button??

Comment: Yes your are right i dont know why too im strugeling with this function a long time brain got tired. im trying to animate slider1 & slider2

Comment: A victim of XY problem? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem